# What podcasts should every freelance designer listen to?

Tags: designers, freelance

I listen to many podcasts every day. When I'm in my car, on my bike, before I fall asleep, and in other rooms in the house that I shouldn't mention here. 
Most of them are about the business side of being a freelancer.

What podcasts are you listening to as freelance designers? I'd like to find some new ones!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's funny you ask - Creative Bloq actually published an article on this with a list of the top 10 podcasts, [here it is](http://www.creativebloq.com/design/best-podcasts-designers-12121517)!

There's also the [graphic designer podcast site](http://graphicdesignerpodcast.com/about/), they don't strictly talk about design there is some business stuff too but there are interviews also :)

Oh and [Gomedia](http://gomedia.us/zine/inspiration/web-roundup/15-design-podcasts-you-should-be-listening-to/) published a top 15, some cross over with Creative Bloq's top 10 so they're double-y recommended.

Happy listening, hope you like some of them - Design Matters is a great one!

Answer (score 0):

First, I have to give an appropriate plug to my own show, [The Busy Creator](http://busycreator.com/podcast/), but there are some others I listen to:

- Design Matters with Debbie Millman
- Page Break
- Freelance Transformation
- Businessology
- Boagworld
- The Rookie Designer
- Clients from Hell
- Online Marketing Made Easy with Amy Porterfield

... and a whole lot more! Look up one of these on iTunes and check the suggestions at the bottom. You'll find a few more.